# NGINX basic auth, problem with location of proxied content

Tags: regex, nginx, basic-authentication, nginx-location

the task is to block following content: /api/ldap-adapter/swagger-ui.html
In NGINX default.conf, we already used following location:

```
location ~ /api(?<p_uri>.*) {
    #https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p
    set $gateway "http://tasks.gateway:8050";
    proxy_pass $gateway$p_uri?$args;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

When I simply try to block it with wildcard or exact match:
wildcard:

```
location ~* \.html$ {
    auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
```

exact match:

```
location = /api/ldap-adapter/swagger-ui.html {
        auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
```

I have following error:

```
2019/12/20 10:41:18 [error] 39#39: *39 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/ldap-adapter/swagger-ui.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.255.0.5, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ldap-adapter/swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1",
```

Nginx use some default prefix of location: /usr/share/nginx/html..

How can I block everything with  swagger-ui for example ?

Comment: The `location` block must be complete. You need to duplicate the `proxy` statements into the new `location` block, otherwise, Nginx will attempt to serve a static file from its default root.

Comment: I done this, but I' got again 404. How  I should define location ?
location ~ /api(?<p_uri>.swagger-ui*) ?